# Java Convert From 'For' Statement to Nested While Statement

Tags: java, loops

Convert the following code so that it uses nested while statements instead of for statements.

Below is the original code with a for loop to be converted to a nested while loop:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
   int s =0;
   int t =1;

   for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     s = s = i;
     for (int j =i; j >0; j --)
     {
         t = t + (j-1);
     }
     s = s + t;
```

What I currently have is below:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int s = 0;
int t = 1;

while ( i < 5)
{
    s = s + i;

     while (j > 0)
     {
         t = t + (j -1);
     }
       i++;
       j--;
```

This produces the output of:
T is 1,
T is 1,
T is 1,
T is 1,
T is 1,
S is 10

What it should produce is:
T is 1,
T is 1,
T is 2,
T is 5,
T is 11,
S is 30

- Now in the first loop, that needs to be converted, I understand that 'S' is going through the loop adding '1' unto itself until it exceeds 5 then it will drop down to the "for" loop and continue on with those operations. However, what I don't understand is after completing the operations for 'S' ,which adds to 30, and dropping down to the second 'for' statement- where does 'j' come from? For instance, the first statement int j = i; is that asking if int j is equal to the entire sum of 'S'?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: `s = s = i` What? Why?

Comment: I was just copying the statement from the original 'for' statement. I didn't assume that would change in the process of going from a 'for' to a nested 'while'.

Comment: Right, it changes nothing, `s = s` does exactly nothing. Is your question answered or do you still need help?

Comment: I appreciate you counseling me through my noobness.

Comment: No problem, try [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decrement `j` inside int own while loop which is the second while loop.
also before the while loop you need to initialize `j=i` like you are doing in for loop.

code:

```
while ( i < 5)
{
    s = s + i;

    j=i;
    while (j > 0)
    {
       t = t + (j -1);
       j--;
    }
    i++;
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.